# Simplifying regex to replace underscores adhering to some substring logic

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, substring

The input string is:

```
s = 'The\ue000 Project\ue000Gutenber g\ue000 E Book \ue000of\ue000 The\ue000 Ad vent ure s\ue000of\ue000 Sherlock\ue000 Holmes\n '
```

And the output string is:

```
o = 'The Project Gutenber_ _g E_ _Book of The Ad_ _vent_ _ure_ _s of Sherlock Holmes\n'
```

Note that from the input string, the `\ue000` are the hard delimiters between words.

The aim is to do something like this:

[image]

- [Cell 28]: replace the spaces with an underscore (to represent that there is a connection between two non-`\ue000` characters)
- [Cell 29]: then if there are `_ \uE000` sequences, remove the underscore since there's no connections between the previous char ending with the underscore and the next word, (remember `\ue000` is a hard word delimiter).
- [Cell 30]: then replace the `\ue000` with a space, so we're left with words with underscores that are either connected to an ending char of words or underscores hanging between two spaces:
- [Cell 31]: deduplicate the spaces
- [Cell 32]: delete the underscore hanging between two spaces
- [Cell 33]: now that we're left with the underscores attached to the end of words, we can safely replace them with `_ _` to indicate that the two sub-words are combinable.

The full set of replacements in the order described above:

```
text = text.replace(u'\n ', '\n')
text = text.replace(u' ', '_ ')
text = text.replace(u'_ \uE000', u' \uE000')
text = text.replace(u"\uE000", u' ')
text = text.replace(u'  ', u' ')
text = text.replace(u' _ ', u' ')
text = text.replace(u'_ ', u'_ _')
text = text.replace(u'  ', u' ')
```

Note: the first replacement for `text.replace(u'\n ', '\n')` is necessary because the string could have been a full text file and simply using `str.strip()` would not be sufficient to clear out the non-necessary spaces between the `\n` and the new line.

**Is there a less convoluted way to achieve the same output string** that keeps the logic of why the replacements are done in the way described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite follow your penultimate paragraph regarding newlines, but that aside, a single `re.sub()` is sufficient to get you most of the way:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.sub(r'[ \ue000]+', lambda m: ' ' if '\ue000' in m.group() else '_ _', s)
'The Project Gutenber_ _g E_ _Book of The Ad_ _vent_ _ure_ _s of Sherlock Holmes\n_ _'
```

This finds all sequences of `\ue000` and spaces, then replaces those sequences using a lambda that returns either a space or  `'_ _'` depending on whether the match contains `\ue000`.

After that, as far as I can tell (as I said, your penultimate paragraph is somewhat confusing), you just need to strip underscores and spaces:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[ \ue000]+', lambda m: ' ' if '\ue000' in m.group() else '_ _', s).strip('_ ')
'The Project Gutenber_ _g E_ _Book of The Ad_ _vent_ _ure_ _s of Sherlock Holmes\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, no worries about the newline. That can be done one step before =) BTW, would `r'[\s\ue000]+'` be better?

Comment: The only difference would be that using `\s` would match sequences of all whitespace (including tab and newline) plus `\ue000` - I don't know whether that matches your data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: nope, ` ` is better than `\s` explicitly only the spacebar whitespace is important, the `\n` must be treated differently.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!